# Error 42000 en consulta SQL al intentar restauar base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7, pdo

estoy aprendiendo MySQL actualmente y como ejercicio nos mandaron a hacer un sistema que creara un respaldo de la base de datos de alguna app que estuviesemos usando/creando/editando etc., y luego ademas por supuesto lo restaurase. Ya habia creado la pagina que se encargaba de la creacion del archivo de respaldo, el problema esta en la parte de la restauración, permitanme dar un poco más de contexto:

La app es un sitio e-commerce del estilo carrito de compras, al momento de resturar la base de datos, casi todos los datos se restauran/sobreescriben, el problema esta en la tabla "Products" en la que tengo algunos articulos de ejemplo para la tienda, no entiendo muy bien pero diria que el error esta relacionado a algun caracter especial que poseen algunos campos de texto, en alguna columna dentro de la tabla.

Este es el codigo que habia intentado seguir para ejecutar el respaldo:

`$conn = $pdo->open();`

```
    try{
        
$backup_file = "backup.sql";
$sql = file_get_contents($backup_file);
        
$queries = explode(";", $sql);

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    if (trim($query) !== "") {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare(filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    
}
    
    $_SESSION['sucess'] = 'El sistema se restauro correctamente';
        
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    

    $pdo->close();

}
```

**Y este es el error que estoy obteniedo luego de ejecutar el respaldo:**

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''15-inch laptop ideal for gamers. Featuring the latest Intel®' at line 1`

Aqui adjunto el link a lo que seria una copia casi exacta del respaldo en .sql que estoy cargando (la unica diferencia es que no hay información sensible, pero el error aun asi se replica igualmente).

https://justpaste.it/4or4a

Agradecido de antemano con cualquier samaritano amigable que me pueda ayudar :)

Comment: ¿Por qué usas PHP? Los respaldos de suelen restaurar en consola directamente.

Comment: Soy consciente, pero fue una asignacion que nos dejaron en la facultad, si por mi fuese lo dejaria para que el admin lo respalde desde la consola :,)

Comment: En consola, bastaría con esto: **`mysql -u tuNombeDeUsuarioDeLaBD -p elNombreDeLaBaseDeDatos < laRutaCorrectaYElNombreDelArchivo`** Te pedirá la contraseña para la conexión, se la pones y listo, tendrás tus datos listos, si está todo OK en el archivo `.sql`.

Comment: ¿Cuál fue la asignación exactamente? Hacer lo que pretendes con `file_get_contents` es prácticamente  imposible con un archivo producido por `mysqldump`, porque como ves el archivo tiene comentarios y demás, no es estrictamente un archivo con sólo las consultas y un separador por cada una. Si tienes que hacerlo en entorno PHP sí o sí podrías ejecutar un comando desde PHP que cargue el archivo en la base de datos por ejemplo. Pero en fin, no le veo el sentido a ciertos requerimientos.

Comment: El problema en tu caso, si observas, es que supuestamente cada instrucción SQL estaría separada por `;`, pero eso no se cumple en el caso de la tabla `products`, la cual en sus columnas tiene contenidos que usan también punto y coma, por ejemplo: `15-inch laptop ideal for gamers. Featuring the latest Intel&reg; processors for superior gaming performance, and life-like NVIDIA&reg; GeForce&reg;` eso te rompe toda la lógica. Tendrías que intentar buscar otro separador, si es que existe, para determinar las diferentes consultas. Por eso te decía, es un requerimiento extraño y que no tiene sentido.

Comment: L asignación tal cual decia: "Presenten un sistema propio o modificado al que hayan implementado generación de respaldos de base de datos, a su vez se debe permitir al usuario restaurar el sistema mediante dicho respaldo", investigue un poco y lo primero que encontre era realizar el respaldo usando mysqldump, luego la parte de la restauracion desde el codigo me parecio todo un rollo innecesario como comentas, tienes de casusalidad alguna idea de como hacer esto de otra forma más eficiente?

Comment: La asignación no te impide lo que te vengo diciendo. PHP te permite interactuar con el shell, que es donde está la base de datos. Es incluso un enfoque más interesante, porque trabajas a un nivel más bajo, sin capas intermedias para la conexión y demás. Mediante [`shell_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) tú puedes mandar el comando que te indicaba más arriba, pasándole la contraseña de conexión y el restore se haría de una forma directa, como si estuvieras en la consola. Si por algún motivo o restricción no pudieras hacerlo así, puedes programar ...

Comment: ... un script de consola y llamarlo desde PHP y en ese script te conectas a la base de datos y ejecutas el comando para restaurar.

Comment: ¡Mil gracias! He hecho el codigo a traves del shell exec, añadi un par de exepciones y catch,  y ha funcionado tal cual queria, te agradezco mucho :D